# Haproxy won't start on Macos

Tags: haproxy

When I run `brew services reload haproxy`, I get:

```
==> Successfully stopped `haproxy` (label: homebrew.mxcl.haproxy)
==> Successfully started `haproxy` (label: homebrew.mxcl.haproxy)
```

However, when I run `brew services info haproxy`, I get:

```
haproxy (homebrew.mxcl.haproxy)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
```

And if I `cat /opt/homebrew/var/log/haproxy.log`, I get:

```
[NOTICE]   (24229) : haproxy version is 2.8.1-a90123a
[WARNING]  (24229) : [/opt/homebrew/opt/haproxy/bin/haproxy.main()] Failed to drop supplementary groups. Using 'gid'/'group' without 'uid'/'user' is generally useless.
```

In my `haproxy.cfg`, I have:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        stats timeout 30s
        user root
        group staff
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # p80 - FrontEnd Configuration
  #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  frontend p80
      bind 0.0.0.0:80
      mode http

      option httplog
      option dontlognull
      option httpclose
      option forwardfor

      log-format "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r"
      capture request header Host len 40
      capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 40


      acl request_the_app url_beg -i /the_app

      use_backend the_app if  request_the_app

backend the_app
  http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/the_app/,/)]
  http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/the_app,/)]
  server the_app 127.0.0.1:4000 check
```

I attempted changing `group staff` in my `haproxy.cfg` to `group wheel`, `group daemon`, and so on.  I tried commenting out `daemon` as well. I originally had

```
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /opt/homebrew/bin/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
```

in my `haproxy.cfg` but got rid of all that.

I checked the usergroups on my Macos. My root user does belong to the staff group (I also tried wheel). If I try my personal login username, I get the same result as using root. I've been careful to reload haproxy using `brew services reload haproxy` each time. No dice.

Comment: try stopping the HAProxy service with `brew services stop haproxy` and then start it again with `brew services start haproxy`